# Using `net_adm` modules functions for localhost development nodes

Tags: erlang

I'm poking around with the [`net_adm`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html) module and can't seem to get any joy working with localhost nodes. My machine is named:

```
> hostname
walden
```

and I start up a few local short-named nodes:

```
> erl -sname one -setcookie monster      
Erlang R16B (erts-5.10.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)
(one@walden)1>
```

and

```
> erl -sname two -setcookie monster
Erlang R16B (erts-5.10.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)
(two@walden)1>
```

So far, so good.

```
(two@walden)1> net_adm:names().     
{ok,[{"two",63489},{"one",63491}]}
(two@walden)2> net_adm:localhost().
"walden"
(two@walden)3> net_adm:names().     
{ok,[{"two",63489},{"one",63491}]}
```

Both of the local nodes are registered but they aren't connected, which is expected.

```
(two@walden)4> nodes().
[]
```

Back on node `one`:

```
(one@walden)1> net_adm:names(two). 
{error,nxdomain}
(one@walden)2> net_adm:names('two@walden'). 
{error,nxdomain}
(one@walden)3> net_adm:dns_hostname(two).
{error,two}
(one@walden)4> net_adm:dns_hostname(two@walden).
{error,two@walden}
```

Erlang correctly identifies my localhost as `walden` but `dns_hostname/1` returns an error. Back on `two`:

```
(two@walden)5> net_adm:ping(one@walden).
pong
(two@walden)6> nodes().                 
[one@walden]
```

and

```
(one@walden)5> nodes().
[two@walden]
```

Okay, bummer. It'd be really convenient to use a `.hosts.erlang` file for localhost development nodes--via `net_adm:worlds/0`--but it seems like I'm stuck a bit. Am I missing something or doing something glaringly wrong? Could my overall system be misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a hostname to `names` and `dns_hostname`, not a node name.  It looks like your nodes are already connected to me, since the other shows up when you run `nodes()`.